# Ancient practise of sneaking into women's bedrooms...?

Tags: etymology, definitions, history

I was looking up the meaning of [`スマ婚{こん}`](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1136287801), when my mouse happened to roll over the kanji `婚{こん}`, and this definition popped up in [Rikaichan](http://www.polarcloud.com/rikaichan):

> 婚 よばい ancient practice of creeping at night into a woman's bedroom
>   (lit: night crawling); stealing into a girl's bedroom at night to make
>   love; sneaking visit

Say what? Putting aside the fact that this sounds like a whitewashed description of sexual assault, at what point in history was this "practice" so common that it was given a name?

Is the definition accurate, or is it just another case of [WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C) and its occasionally misguided and erroneous community contributed obscure definitions?

If it is accurate, what is the history behind this word?

Comment: Have you seen 「[辻]{つじ}[斬]{ぎ}り」 yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Nice! I hadn't heard of that word before, but it's a fun one. I have, however, heard of the practice.

Comment: Absolutely can't help on the Japanese word, but regarding the cultural context and your surprise, I would point you to words like "ravish", their 17th~19th century meaning *and* the fact that when people said "taking a woman against **her** will", they often meant "against the will of **her father**", making "ravish" a common face-saving euphemism for "eloping"... I wonder if your word is not of a similar nature.

Comment: @Dave: Interesting insight. I imagine, though, that being against the will of the father doesn't mean the woman was necessarily for it. Rather that the will of the woman was largely secondary to the intentions of both or either the father and the suitor.

Comment: This question is walking a fine line between on- and off-topic.  I would reword it to focus on the etymology of `婚`, etc., rather than asking about historical practices.  Otherwise, it may be closed (as it currently has 1 vote).

Comment: Hahaha! I propose よっぱい！ when you do this a lot, with great success...  最近、よく　よっぱい するよ！

Comment: @istrasci: The question is clearly asking for etymology. And the history sought is only in support of the origin of the word, so I can't see how this is in any way off topic. Not to mention it inspired Jesse's answer which had further insights into the meaning and origin of the word 結婚 and more, which is also of clear relevance. At the very least, it's as on topic as the history of proposals about language after World War two that ultimately didn't change anything about the language and won't teach anyone about any new or old words... just sayin'. ;)

Comment: @DaveMG:  I'm not saying *I* think it's off-topic.  I'm just saying that objectively, asking about historical practices could be seen as off-topic.

Comment: @istrasci: Right... except I'm not asking about historical practises. I'm asking about how a word came to be. The word describes a historical practise, so I think it's pretty unavoidable to learn about what that historical practise is. Just like you can't learn what the word "sushi" means without learning how the food is made, even though this is not a cooking site.

Comment: @DaveMG:  OK, you convinced me!

Comment: @istrasci: Glad we could come to agree! :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Say what? Putting aside the fact that this sounds like a whitewashed description of sexual assault, at what point in history was this "practice" so common that it was given a name?

I don't know when it started, but the word originally comes from [呼ばう]{よばう} and is more commonly written as [夜這い]{よばい}. It is an old Japanese custom that was common up until the Meiji or Taisho Period and originally was thought of as a way to propose to a girl (I use the word "propose" very loosely here). However, in very local areas, it supposedly lasted up until around World War II.

> Is the definition accurate, or is it just another case of WWWJDIC and its occasionally misguided and erroneous community contributed obscure definitions?

It is misleading. The way we think of two people meeting, falling in love and getting married is very different from what went on in the olden days in Japan. There was also no concept of "cheating on your spouse", etc. the way we think of nowadays. 
Basically every small village had a set of customs or rules which everyone would abide by. よばい refers to a custom were men were allowed to go to the place where a girl was sleeping, and if the girl approved, make love. Now, if the girl refused, you were supposed to leave or else the father would come and haul the guy away. However, sexual assault did occur sometimes, and よばい *sometimes* does implicitly imply that. Also, in some villages, if you didn't abide by the rules, there would be some kind of punishment involved.

However, every village was different. In some areas it was common for women to sneak into guys rooms, or they would hold a festival of girls (or guys) who "became of age" where older people would teach them how to have sex. Also, a lot of times you would have sex with so many different people, nobody really knew who their real father was. The examples I'm giving are just some of the customs that were present, but I'm sure there are a lot more. Also, the idea of "marriage" in Japan was when you could regularly go to a girl's house without sneaking. The word 結婚 itself didn't actually exist till the Meiji Era because there was no word to translate "marry"*

*: It should be noted that there were words that meant "becoming a couple" in Japanese, such as [婚姻]{こんいん} that existed before the word 結婚, but they didn't mean the same thing as the word "marriage" in English.

**References**

- [夜這い](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%9C%E9%80%99%E3%81%84) - Wikipedia Article
- [田舎の『夜這い』文化についてご存知の方いますか？](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2605907.html)
- [結婚の語源](http://www.7key.jp/data/word_custom/kekkon.html)

Comment: +1 for a really well written answer. The only thing I'd add to this is that this practise is referenced in the introduction to this (http://www.amazon.com/Genji-Penguin-Classics-Deluxe-Editions/dp/014243714X) version of 源氏物語. I can't remember the exact passage, otherwise I'd add it.

Comment: I'd love to see some references, especially for the marriage/結婚 bit.  I believe 夜這い, between one thing and another, but I've never had any references I could swear by for this kind of thing.

Comment: @SomethingJapanese: I added some references. However, they are all in Japanese.

Comment: Now there are "rabu ho" for that. So what has changed, really.

Comment: @Kaz: "Rabu ho"?

Comment: @DaveMG: It an abbreviation for "ラブホテル".

Comment: @Jesse: Ah. My brain sometimes doesn't parse romaji, even when it should be obvious... ;)

Comment: http://www.rabuho.com/

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Thank you for correcting my poor English grammar :).